# How to build a tree from a list of nodes' parents?

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, hierarchy

I know the parent for each node. It is stored in a flat `unordered_map`. Each node is just a number where zero means root. How can I efficiently create a tree from that information?

```
struct node {
    int id;
    unordered_set<node> children;
};
```

It may occur that some nodes are not attached to the root at all. Those detached chains can be ignored and don't need to be part of the resulting tree.

Please ask for more information if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array of node pointers.

Then go through the map, adding the node at the given index in the array to `children` of the node at the index in the array of its parent.

Then the node at index `0` will be the root of the tree.

Comment: "Then the node at index 0 will be the root of the tree." Why would that be? Surely the node without parent (or with itself being its own parent) is the root.

Comment: Using pointers is fine. The root is already given by id zero.

Comment: @G.Bach Well, from the question statement it would appear that `0` is the root (and there are detached chains, so simply looking for the one without the parent won't work).

Comment: I think using points really does the trick here. However, I'd prefer using `unordered_set` instead of an array. What do you think?

Comment: @danijar That should also work. An array would probably be preferred if you know the size ahead of time and you're going to create all the nodes, because there's a fair amount of time and space overhead to `unordered_set`.